# how to put web browser into an ios app?

Tags: swift, web, browser

I need to put web browser into my ios app (I use Swift).  How can I add that? Thanks!

Comment: A couple of words to search for are `WKWebView` and `WebView`. That might help you in your search :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Xcode in the Object Library you will find a WebView.

[image: Object Lbrary]

You place it inside your View and drag an Outlet like you usually do with a button/textField ...

[image: in code]

I let you the documentation to know how to play with this view.

Answer (score 3):

1. Drag the `UIWebView` inside your `UIViewController` from the object library
2. Set the outlet: `@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView`
3. Instantiate a `NSURLRequest`, with a `NSURL` object set with the right URL as string, and finally, assign this `NSURLRequest` to the web view by calling `loadRequest`:

   ```
   let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
   let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
   webView.loadRequest(request)
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I used webview a lot by loading web contents. Now I understand the key is to initiate with a website, like google.